# Hidden Value For each Div on Page

Tags: php, ajax

How can I have Two hidden value specifically for each DIV I have, first of all, is that possible?
let's look at here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <div id="one">
    Hello World 1
   <input type="hidden" id="one" value="one">

  </div>

  <div id="two">
    Hello World 2
    <input type="hidden" id="two" value="two">

  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Is it really possible...Some idea please?

I have tried to get as usual $_POST Method But how do I deferntiate which post is for which div?

This is all handle in PHP, then I will call that in Ajax. so some idea?

Comment: simply add name attribute to your hidden fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your own standard having the two hidden divs based on a formula 'hidden_'{index}'_'{div_name}:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.10.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() 
        {
            $('div').click(function()
            {
                var element = $(this).attr( "id" );
                var value1  = $('#hidden_1_'+element).attr( "value" ); 
                var value2  = $('#hidden_2_'+element).attr( "value" ); 
                $_data = 'var1='+value1+'&var2='+value2;
                $.post("script.php",$_data,
                   function(data)
                   {
                      response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                      console.log(response);
                   }
               );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="one">
    Hello World 1
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_1_one" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_2_one" value="2">
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    Hello World 2
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_1_two" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_2_two" value="4">
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Then code the script.php, and response is json...

Then with the two objects you can do whatever you want, then see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-3

Comment: please help me here on ajax, If the value is hidden_1_one in id one show the next data, how do I do in ajax...

Comment: what I do is loading next data after some delay if the value is some string like hidden_1_one, how do i achieve in ajax, Help please?

Comment: Fully functional now, just make the script.php and include jQuery

Comment: I have open another question, here please check...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423540/show-next-value-from-mysql-php-in-ajax

Answer (score 4):

For get by $_POST you need put the '**name**' **attribute** to the input:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="one" name="one" value="one">
```

Comment: But is that specific to the DIV content

Comment: I mean the dive has different content comes from database, so If Div ID is (one) is accomplished then show next data in div one

Comment: With the input value you can filter if is div(one) or div(two). no?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="hidden" name="div2" id="two" value="two">
```

Should give you the variable div2 in your POST, assuming you submit the fields using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as much hidden inputs for each div as you wish, just don't give them the same id. And to see them in `$_POST`, you need to give each input a `name`:

```
<div id="one">
    Hello World 1
   <input type="hidden" id="one_1" value="one" name="one_first">
   <input type="hidden" id="one_2" value="one" name="one_second">
</div>

<div id="two">
    Hello World 2
   <input type="hidden" id="two_1" value="tow" name="two_first">
   <input type="hidden" id="two_2" value="two" name="two_second">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `for POST data, you should give any name to the element.`

Secondly, if you want to access hidden elements with respect to div, give some relative names.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 
    <div id="one">
    Hello World 1
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_1_one" name="hidden_1_one" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_2_one" name="hidden_1_one" value="2">
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    Hello World 2
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_1_two" name="hidden_1_two"  value="3">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_2_two" name="hidden_2_two" value="4">
  </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And Now you can easily post hidden element related to that DIV.